# How to make API call in Kotlin Using Retrofit (Android) with nested JSON APIs

Tags: android, json, api, kotlin, retrofit

The below code is working fine and I am able to fetch data from it. But I want to do the same with a different API here is the API: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/p57gxwqm84zkp96/demo_api.json . I am new to APIs and I don't know how to fetch data from this API. Can someone please help and explain how to do it?

NOTE:
I have made data classes of this second API using the "Kotlin Data class file from JSON" plugin.

**## activity_main.xml ##**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDesc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/textview"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**## MainActivity.kt ##**

```
package com.example.apiproject

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.TextView
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Callback
import retrofit2.Response
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory

const val BASE_URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/"

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        getMyData();
    }

    private fun getMyData() {
        val retrofitBuilder = Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .build()
            .create(APIInterface::class.java)

        val retrofitData = retrofitBuilder.getData()

        retrofitData.enqueue(object : Callback<List<MyDataItem>?> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<MyDataItem>?>, response: Response<List<MyDataItem>?>) {
                val responseBody = response.body()!!

                val myStringBuilder  = StringBuilder()
                for (myData in responseBody){
                    myStringBuilder.append(myData.id)
                    myStringBuilder.append("\n")
                }
                val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtDesc)
                textView.text = myStringBuilder
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<MyDataItem>?>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.d("MainActivity","OnFailure: "+t.message)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

**## APIInterface.kt ##**

```
package com.example.apiproject

import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.http.GET

interface APIInterface {
    @GET("posts")
    fun getData(): Call<List<MyDataItem>>
}
```

**## MyDataItem.kt ##**

```
package com.example.apiproject

data class MyDataItem(
    val body: String,
    val id: Int,
    val title: String,
    val userId: Int
)
```

**## APIInterface.kt ##**

```
package com.example.apiproject

class MyData : ArrayList<MyDataItem>()
```

Comment: What is the problem? Do you see an error?

Comment: There is no error in the above code.

I want to call this API: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/p57gxwqm84zkp96/demo_api.json with the above method.

Please tell me how to do that exactly.

I changed the BASE_URL and the data classes but data is not getting retrieved in textView

Comment: The data in the JSON file is not a list. It is an Object that contains a list of items under: "Result" attribute. Your Kotlin classes are not reflecting this data structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you organized your project structure, I followed you for presentational purposes.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The URL you provided for that I used two data class

**Status.kt**

```
data class Status(
    val Message: String,
    val RecordCount: String,
    val Result: List<Result>,
    val Status: Int
)
```

**Result.kt**

```
data class Result(
    val CategName: String,
    val CurrencySymbol: String,
    val DealCategoryID: String,
    val DealID: String,
    val DealType: String,
    val Description: String,
    val Discount: String,
    val Image: String,
    val MemberTier: String,
    val PromoCode: String,
    val StoreID: String,
    val StoreName: String,
    val TOC: String,
    val Title: String,
    val TowerNumber: String,
    val ValidityEnd: String,
    val ValidityStart: String,
    val isFav: String
)
```

**APIInterface.kt**

```
interface APIInterface {
    @GET("demo_api.json")
    fun getData() : Call<Status>
}
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    val BASE_URL = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/p57gxwqm84zkp96/"
    private val TAG = "MainActivity"
    private lateinit var textView: TextView
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        textView = findViewById(R.id.tvTextView)
        getMyData()
    }

    private fun getMyData() {
        val retrofitBuilder = Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .build()
            .create(APIInterface::class.java)

        val retrofitData = retrofitBuilder.getData()
        retrofitData.enqueue(object : Callback<Status> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<Status>, response: Response<Status>) {
                val responseBody = response.body()!!
                Log.d("Message ", responseBody.Message)
                Log.d("RecordCount ", responseBody.RecordCount)
                Log.d("Status ", responseBody.Status.toString())


                for (i in 0 until responseBody.Result.size) {
                    Log.d("CategName ", responseBody.Result[i].CategName)
                    Log.d("CurrencySymbol ", responseBody.Result[i].CurrencySymbol)
                    Log.d("DealCategoryID ", responseBody.Result[i].DealCategoryID)
                    Log.d("DealID ", responseBody.Result[i].DealID)
                    Log.d("Description ", responseBody.Result[i].DealType)
                    Log.d("Description ", responseBody.Result[i].Description)
                    Log.d("Discount ", responseBody.Result[i].Discount)
                    Log.d("Image ", responseBody.Result[i].Image)
                    Log.d("MemberTier ", responseBody.Result[i].MemberTier)
                    Log.d("PromoCode ", responseBody.Result[i].PromoCode)
                    Log.d("StoreID ", responseBody.Result[i].StoreID)
                    Log.d("StoreName ", responseBody.Result[i].StoreName)
                    Log.d("TOC ", responseBody.Result[i].TOC)
                    Log.d("Title ", responseBody.Result[i].Title)
                    Log.d("TowerNumber ", responseBody.Result[i].TowerNumber)
                    Log.d("ValidityEnd ", responseBody.Result[i].ValidityEnd)
                    Log.d("ValidityStart ", responseBody.Result[i].ValidityStart)
                    Log.d("isFav ", responseBody.Result[i].isFav + "\n\n")
                }

            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Status>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.d(TAG, "OnFailure: " + t.message)

            }

        }
        )
    }
}
```

For presentation purposes I used Logcat. It will be best if you can use recyclerview..

Comment: If you don't mind can you please share your social profile so that I can ask if I have some doubts?

Comment: If you have any doubts, please share this problem here. I think the most experienced developers are here and give you the best solution for your problems.

Comment: Did this solve your issue? If yes mark this answer was helpful so that others will not answer unnecessarily.